# Unexpectedly found nil in swift with UIProgressView

Tags: swift, uiprogressview

I've created a progressView and linked it like this:
[image: progressview]

And here is what I do in my view controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!
     @IBOutlet weak var KronosWebsite: WKWebView!

     override func loadView() {
         //initialize the webview
         progressView = UIProgressView()
         
         progressView.progress = 1.0

         KronosWebsite = WKWebView()
         self.view = KronosWebsite
         self.view.addSubview(progressView)
     }
 }
```

And I've got

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional

in this line `progressView.progress = 1.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `super.loadView()`  when you use `loadView` for a vc that originally inside storyboard

```
 override func loadView() {
     super.loadView()
```

or insert all code inside `viewDidLoad` , also don't  re-init

```
progressView = UIProgressView() 
KronosWebsite = WKWebView()
```

as they already initiated from storyboard

Comment: Ok thanks SH_Khan super.loadView()  was the thing that was missing

Comment: also remove the re-init 2 lines above

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) say to never override `loadView` if your view controller comes from a storyboard or xib:

> **loadView()**
>
> If you use Interface Builder to create your views and initialize the view controller, you must not override this method.

Everything that you're currently doing in `loadView` can be done in the storyboard anyway, so just remove the `loadView` method and connect your `UIProgressView` and `WKWebView` to your outlets in your storyboard. You can also set the progress view's initial progress to 1.0 inside the storyboard.